# Ввод односвязного списка

Tags: c++, указатели, структуры, список

Есть один небольшой вопрос. У меня есть список с двумя полями данных (одно для буквы, а второе для числа). Он вводиться с клавиатуры. Пример: 11a33v55b. Но проблема в том, что ввод не прекращаться после нажатие enter. Нужно в конце ввести какой-нибудь / или . или любой знак не число и не буква. Тогда вызывается функция вывода. То-есть 11a33v55b/. А нужно чтобы 11a33v55b нажал enter и ввод закончился.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct A
{
    int cyfra;
    char symbol;
};

struct List
{
    A a;
    List* next;
};

List * get_AList_item() {
    List *elem = new List;

    if (cin >> elem->a.cyfra >> elem->a.symbol)
        return elem;

    return 0;
}

List *get_list() {
    List *head = get_AList_item(), 
        *tail = head;             
    while ((tail->next = get_AList_item()))
        tail = tail->next;

    return head;  
}

int main() {
    // Получить заполненный список
    List *list = get_list();

    // поэлементно распечатать его
    cout << "List:\n";
    for (List *p = list; p; p = p->next)
        cout << p->a.cyfra << p->a.symbol << ' ';
}
```

Comment: введите символ конца ввода  вашей системы. У меня он Ctrl + z

Comment: @ARHovsepyan если честно, то не очень понимаю о чем Вы

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/EOF.   Ваш код допускает утечку памяти, подумайте еше и об этом

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Хорошо. Понял про ето. Но я так понимаю, что нельзя сделать вывод списка по нажатию enter?

Comment: так как вы написали, нельзя, но вообше возможно

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, если ввод происходит строкой, как в вашем примере, то можете воспользоваться следующей конструкцией:

```
std::string str;
std::getline(std::cin, str);
```

А потом просто парсить вашу строку в список как вам угодно, хоть регулярку для нее написать)

Answer (score 1):

Как уже указали в ответе, воспользуйтесь вводом строк и чтением элементов списка из потока (класс `stringstream`), связанного с введенной строкой.

Для реализации таких изменений добавьте пару заголовочных файлов

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
```

и немного модифицируйте функции ввода

```
List * get_AList_item(stringstream &cin) {
// имя аргумента специально выбрано `cin`, оно "перебьет" стандартное значение, 
// что позволит не менять код функции
//     далее тот же код
....
}
```

В функцию `get_list()` потребуется внести побольше изменений

```
List *get_list() {
    string s;
    getline(cin, s);
    stringstream ss(s);

    // далее единственное изменение кода, вызов `get_AList_item` с параметром
    List *head = get_AList_item(ss), 
        *tail = head;             
    while ((tail->next = get_AList_item(ss)))
        tail = tail->next;

    return head;  
}
```

Вот, собственно и все.